# why TransactionManager in spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have developed an Apache axis2 webservice with spring integration. In that Data access module I have managed with spring JdbcTemplate. With the help of JdbcTemplate we can execute all type of queries(ddl,dml etc). then why TransactionManager in spring?

when to use JdbcTemplate and when to use TransactionManager in spring?
please give me a clarity..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The usage of `JdbcTemplate` or a `TransactionManager` is not a question of "either the one or the other". Look at the fabulous [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/) thus showing your effort and state a specific question.